# Adding single quotes to character after a particular string

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file which consists of a string ,I am parsing the file for my further purpose ,I want to parse  by adding a single quote to a character after a particular string ,How to do that??

```
Text file data:
{Name:{ID:12342,age:32},type:s},{Name:{ID:12345,age:42},type:t},{Name:{ID:12348,age:35},type:s},{Name:{ID:12349,age:55},type:t}
```

Here I want to add a single quote to character after type:''

```
Expected o/p: 
{Name:{ID:12342,age:32},type:'s'},{Name:{ID:12345,age:42},type:'t'},{Name:    {ID:12348,age:35},type:'s'},{Name:{ID:12349,age:55},type:'t'}
```

My java code:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Workspace/JAVA/Sample/EMP.txt"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
               String  value = sb.toString();
```

Comment: It looks like json, why don't you use a json-parser?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below `string.replceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=:)([a-zA-Z]+)", "'$1'");
```

This would add single quotes around the word(*only letters*) which exists next to the colon.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/91)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=type:)([^,}]*)
```

Try this.Replace by `'$1'`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/89

Comment: Working, but only for the 1st string  type:'s' ,Remaining its not adding

Comment: @RameshK use `g` flag or `replaceall`